# How can I correctly add Items to a cart in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to move some items from a modal to a page I have kept for orders. It's kind of similar to a cart. I am able to get the items to display in the console but when I add them and go check the orders page I cant see the items I just added.

This is the JSX code for the modal

```
class pizzaModal extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: "small",
    showModal: true,
    showOrders: false,
    orders: []
  }
  toggleHandler = (size)=> ()=>{
    this.setState({
            toggle: size
        });
  }
  addToOrders = (productName, productIngredients, productPrice, productImage)=>{
    this.setState(prevState=>({
      orders: [...prevState.orders, productImage, productName, productIngredients, productPrice]
    }))
  }
  
  render (){
    let attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer]
    if(this.state.toggle==='small'){
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Small]
    }
    if(this.state.toggle==="medium"){
      attachedClasses = [styles.ImageContainer, styles.Medium]
    }
    if(this.state.toggle==="large"){
      attachedClasses=[styles.ImageContainer, styles.Large]
    }
    return (
      <Aux>
        { this.state.showOrders?
          <Orders
                  pizzaName={this.state.orders[2]}
                  pizzaImage={this.state.orders[1]}
                  pizzaIngredients={this.state.orders[3]}
                  pizzaPrice={this.state.orders[0]}/>:
           null}
        <div className={styles.Pizzamodal}>
          <div className={styles.ModalContainer}>
            <div className={attachedClasses.join(' ')}>
              <img  src={this.props.image} alt="pizzapicture"/>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.DetailsContainer}>
              <div>
                <div className={styles.TextDetails}>
                  <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                  <p>{this.props.ingredients}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <div className={styles.Form}>
                <form className={styles.switchButton}>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="small" value="small" onChange={this.toggleHandler("small")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="small"}/>
                  <label for="small">Small</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="medium" value="medium" onChange={this.toggleHandler("medium")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="medium"}/>
                  <label for="medium">Medium</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pizza" id="large" value="large" onChange={this.toggleHandler("large")}
                            checked={this.state.toggle==="large"}/>
                  <label for="large">Large</label>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.orderButton}>
                  <button onClick={(productImage, productName,productIngredients, productPrice)=>this.addToOrders(
                    productImage=this.props.image, 
                    productName=this.props.name, 
                    productIngredients=this.props.ingredients, 
                    productPrice=this.props.price )}>Add to basket for ₦{this.props.price}</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>  
            <div className={styles.Navbar} onClick={this.props.clicked}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          </div>
         
      </div>
      </Aux>
    )
  }
}
```

JSX code for the Orders Page

```
const orders = (props)=>{
  return(
    <div>
       <div className={Styles.OrderHeader}>
         <div>
          <img src={Logo} alt="logo"/>
          <h1>DODO PIZZA</h1>
         </div> 
        </div>  
        <h1 className={Styles.OrderContentContainerHeader}>My order</h1>
       <div className={Styles.OrderContentContainer}>
          <div className={Styles.OrderContent}>
            <div>
               <div style={{paddingRight: '80px'}}>
                 <img src={props.pizzaImage} alt="pizza"/>
               </div>
               <div>
                 <h1>{props.pizzaName}</h1>
                 <p>{props.pizzaIngredients}</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div className={Styles.OrderContentPrice}>
               <div><span>1</span></div>
               <div><span>₦{props.pizzaPrice}</span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={Styles.OrderContent}>
            <div>
               <div style={{paddingRight: '80px'}}>
                 <img src={Sides} alt="sides"/>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <h1>Sausage Roll</h1>
                  <p style={{textOverflow: 'ellipsis', 
                            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>1 pcs</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div className={Styles.OrderContentPrice}>
               <div><span>1</span></div>
               <div><span>₦2,700</span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={Styles.OrderContent}>
            <div>
               <div style={{paddingRight: '80px'}}>
                 <img src={Desserts} alt="desserts"/>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <h1>Ice Cream Straciatella</h1>
                  <p style={{textOverflow: 'ellipsis', 
                            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>1 pcs</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div className={Styles.OrderContentPrice}>
               <div><span>1</span></div>
               <div><span>₦2,700</span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={Styles.OrderContent}>
            <div>
               <div style={{paddingRight: '80px'}}>
                 <img src={Drinks} alt="drinks"/>
               </div>
               <div>
                 <h1>Fanta</h1>
                 <p style={{textOverflow: 'ellipsis', 
                            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>
                              1 pcs</p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div className={Styles.OrderContentPrice}>
               <div><span>1</span></div>
               <div><span>₦2,700</span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div> 
       <div className={Styles.OrderPlacement}>
         <h1>Dipping Sauces</h1>
         <h1>Total: ₦4500</h1>
         <div className={Styles.ButtonContainer}>
          <button>Back to menu</button>
          <button>Next</button>
         </div> 
       </div>
```

For the Orders page, I would like to display the pizza information dynamically based on what I get from the modal but I can't see it. I can see the information "this.state.orders[0] to [3]" in the modal but nothing gets added to the orders page.

Comment: You should keep your orders state in a place where it's accessible to both orders page and modal. You can use React Context API or solution like Redux.

Comment: The Orders Folder is just directly above the folder for the modal. Both are in the same component folder.

Comment: You should try what @DaniloGacevic mentioned, the issue here is that orders array is a state only in PizzaModal component, and orders component does not have access to it.